# AtomicLong vs Long performance

Tags: java, performance, atomic

Context:
I am using netty and have defined a handler in order to count and categorize incoming/outgoing traffic. For this I have used an enumMap that looks like this:

```
EnumMap<MyEnum, AtomicLong>
```

However now I have realized that there is only one thread that is manipulating the values (previously I thought it was more than one, netty seems to guarantee that one thread per channel). This means that AtomicLong is not necessary. **However, as AtomicLong is a wrapper for a primitive long meanwhile Long is an immutable type, I have a reason to think that just swapping AtomicLong to Long will be less performant.**

**Any ideas on this?**

What I probably should do is to move to int and remove the whole enumMap thing..

BR
Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have only one thread:

AtomicLong can be faster than using Long, if it avoid object creation.

Fast again is to use `long[]` or not use objects at all with a collection like [TObjectLongHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectLongHashMap.html)

Comment: This was what I meant. As these counters will be bumped quite frequently (can be more than 10 000 times per second), it feels really unnecessary to create new objects.

Comment: If you are only collecting statistics, you might consider using the thread unsafe version even if this means there is be a small error on the values collected. For counters which increment often this can mean a ~1% error but have lower overhead. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can't image that given:

> in order to count and categorize incoming/outgoing traffic

that a conversion from `AtomicLong` to `Long` (or `long`) will have any impact at all upon your performance.

Comment: couldn't agree more. Don't worry until performance becomes a problem (if it ever does). If it does, profile it and make informed decisions.

Comment: @sjr I am not very keen on that way of coding. Of course very often performance isn't the problem. But if you at least think about it while implementing, you will end up with cleaner code. And if you use comments the right way, readability will not decrease at all.

Comment: See Effective Java (2nd ed.), item 55.

Answer (score 1):

We use LongAdder for the same matter ;)